# Android: Viewing a ListView Item After Delete Operation Views Deleted Item

Tags: android, android-listview, android-studio, android-adapter

I am attempting CRUD operations using SQLite Database in Android for a list view.  I am using a fragment, activity, and a custom base adapter. I can successfully highlight, delete or edit an item, and update the list view and adapters.

I run into a problem when I delete an item (the list view and adapter are updated) and then I attempt to select and highlight an item immediately after.  The edit operation references to the recently deleted item.  When I delete an item and reload the activity everything works as intended.

This is leading me to believe that the list view refresh and database operations are working as intended but the adapter is not updating after a delete.  Perhaps it has something to do with the way I am passing it the selected position for persistent highlighting purposes.

Code is as follows.  Please let me know if you need me to post more or have any morsels of advice for improvement.

ChampionListFragment.java (our primary list view)

`

```
package com.androidtitan.trooptracker.Fragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.androidtitan.alphaarmyapp.R;
import com.androidtitan.trooptracker.Adapter.ChampionAdapter;
import com.androidtitan.trooptracker.Data.DatabaseHelper;
import com.androidtitan.trooptracker.Data.Division;
import com.androidtitan.trooptracker.Data.Soldier;
import com.androidtitan.trooptracker.Interface.ChampionDataPullInterface;
import com.androidtitan.trooptracker.Interface.ChampionInterface;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ChampionListFragment extends Fragment {

DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
ChampionInterface championInterface;
ChampionDataPullInterface pullInterface;

ImageView deleter;
ImageView editer;
ImageView adder;
TextView proceedBtn; //this will "slide" the fragment to

TextView championHeader;
ChampionAdapter adapter;
ListView listView;

Division focusDivision;
Soldier focusSoldier;
ArrayList<Soldier> soldierItems;
List<Soldier> troops;

int selection = -1;
public int receivedIndex = -1;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        championInterface = (ChampionInterface) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }

    try {
        pullInterface = (ChampionDataPullInterface) activity;
    } catch(ClassCastException e) {

        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement MainDataPullInterface");
    }

    receivedIndex = pullInterface.getDivisionIndex();
}

public ChampionListFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
    }

    databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(getActivity());

    soldierItems = new ArrayList<Soldier>();

    troops = databaseHelper.getAllSoldiersByDivision(databaseHelper.getAllDivisions().get(receivedIndex));
    soldierItems.addAll(troops);


    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listView.invalidateViews();
        }
    };

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listview_champion, container, false);

    deleter = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.deleteBtn);
    editer = (ImageView)  getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editBtn);
    adder = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.addBtn);

    championHeader = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.championHeader);
    championHeader.setText(databaseHelper.getAllDivisions().get(receivedIndex).getName());

    listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.championList);
    adapter = new ChampionAdapter(getActivity(), getListItems());
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (!troops.get(position).isSelected()) {

                troops.get(position).setIsSelected(true);

                if (selection != -1) {
                    troops.get(selection).setIsSelected(false);
                }

                selection = position;
                championInterface.setListViewSelection(selection);

            }
            else {

                troops.get(position).setIsSelected(false);

                selection = -1;
                listView.invalidateViews();

                championInterface.setListViewSelection(-1);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i <= listView.getLastVisiblePosition() - listView.getFirstVisiblePosition(); i++) {

                View item = listView.getChildAt(i);
                item.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
            }
            view.setBackgroundColor(0xCC448AFF);

            Log.e("CLFonItemClick", troops.get(position).getfName() + " " + troops.get(position).isSelected());

        }
    });

    deleter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(selection != -1) {

                focusDivision = databaseHelper.getAllDivisions().get(receivedIndex);
                focusSoldier = databaseHelper.getAllSoldiersByDivision(focusDivision).get(selection);

                for(Soldier s : troops) {
                    s.setIsSelected(false);
                }

                databaseHelper.deleteSoldier(focusSoldier);

                adapter.removeItem(selection);

                selection = -1;
                Log.e("CLFdeleter", "selection: " + String.valueOf(selection));

                championInterface.setListViewSelection(-1);

            }

        }
    });

    editer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("CFLediter", "selection: " + String.valueOf(selection));

            if(selection != -1) {
                //this will populate our Adder Fragment
                focusSoldier = soldierItems.get(selection);

                for(Soldier s : troops) {
                    s.setIsSelected(false);
                }
                championInterface.soldierPasser(selection, receivedIndex,
                        focusSoldier.getfName(),
                        focusSoldier.getlName());
            }
        }
    });

    adder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(selection != -1) {
                focusSoldier = soldierItems.get(selection);
                focusSoldier.setIsSelected(false);
            }

            //when we receive our divIndex then that is what we will pass into this method
            championInterface.soldierPasser(selection, receivedIndex, null, null);
        }
    });

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    championInterface = null;
}

private List<Soldier> getListItems() {
    ArrayList<Soldier> soldierItems = new ArrayList<Soldier>();

    if (receivedIndex == -1) {
        soldierItems.addAll(databaseHelper.getAllSoldiers());

    } else {
        soldierItems.addAll(databaseHelper.getAllSoldiersByDivision(databaseHelper.getAllDivisions().get(receivedIndex)));
    }
    return soldierItems;
}


} `
```

ChampionActivity.java

`    package com.androidtitan.trooptracker.Activity;

```
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;

import com.androidtitan.alphaarmyapp.R;
import com.androidtitan.trooptracker.Fragment.ChampionListFragment;
import com.androidtitan.trooptracker.Interface.ChampionInterface;
import com.androidtitan.trooptracker.Interface.ChampionDataPullInterface;

public class ChampionActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ChampionDataPullInterface, ChampionInterface{

ChampionListFragment championFragment;
//ChampionDataPullInterface push4frag2pull;

int divisionIndex;
int selectionIndex = - 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_champion);

    //Data Section

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    divisionIndex = intent.getIntExtra("landingDivision", -1);
    Log.e("ChampAonCreate", "divisionIndex: " + divisionIndex);
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("num", divisionIndex);

    //View Section
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);


    championFragment = new ChampionListFragment();
    championFragment.setArguments(args);


    FragmentTransaction fragTran = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragTran.replace(R.id.championContainer, championFragment, "championFragment").commit();

}


@Override
public void tabInteraction(int id) {

}

@Override
public void soldierPasser(int soldierInt, int divisionInt, String first, String last) {
    Log.e("CAdeleter", "selection " + String.valueOf(soldierInt));


    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AdderActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("editSoloIndex", soldierInt);
    intent.putExtra("editSoloDivIndex", divisionInt);
    intent.putExtra("editSoloFirst", first);
    intent.putExtra("editSoloLast", last);
    startActivity(intent);
}

//this is going to be once we have more fragments such as maps and what's nearby
@Override
public void drawerListViewSelection(int selection) {

}

@Override
public void adderFragDivReference(int divIndex) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AdderActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("divIndex", divIndex);
    ChampionActivity.this.finish();
    startActivity(intent);

}

@Override
public void setListViewSelection(int selection) {
    selectionIndex = selection;
}

public int getListViewSelection() {
    return selectionIndex;
}


@Override
public int getDivisionIndex() {
    return divisionIndex;
}



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LandingActivity.class);
    this.finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}
} `
```

ChampionAdapter.java

`

```
 package com.androidtitan.trooptracker.Adapter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.androidtitan.alphaarmyapp.R;
import com.androidtitan.trooptracker.Activity.ChampionActivity;
import com.androidtitan.trooptracker.Data.DatabaseHelper;
import com.androidtitan.trooptracker.Data.Soldier;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by amohnacs on 6/19/15.
 */

/*
todo:   we need to take the implementation of highlighting our listview items in the adapter form ADDERFRAGMENT
todo:   and implement them in the getView here.
todo:   We might have to deal with passing the 'oldDivision' and 'divSelected' variables
todo:   maybe create some headers.
 */
public class ChampionAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity context;
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

private List<Soldier> adapterData;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

private int selection = -1;

public ChampionAdapter(Activity acontext, List<Soldier> soldiers) {
    this.context = acontext;
    this.adapterData = soldiers;
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return adapterData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return adapterData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return adapterData.get(position).getId();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ListViewHolder viewHolder;

    selection = ((ChampionActivity) context).getListViewSelection();

    if(convertView == null) {
        //inflate the listview_item_row.xml
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.listview_champion_item, null);
        viewHolder = new ListViewHolder();
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    viewHolder.firstItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.champ_text);
    }
    else {
        viewHolder = (ListViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    //ListViewSelection
    if (position == selection) {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(0xCC448AFF);
    }
    else {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    }

    viewHolder.firstItem.setText(adapterData.get(position).getfName() + " "
            + adapterData.get(position).getlName());

    Log.e("CLFonItemClick", adapterData.get(position).getfName() + " " + adapterData.get(position).isSelected());

    return convertView;
}

class ListViewHolder {
    public TextView firstItem;
}

public void removeItem(int itemPosition) {
    //Remove the according group. Dont forget to remove the children aswell!

    adapterData.remove(itemPosition);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    notifyDataSetInvalidated();

}

}`
```

ChampionInterface.java

```
`
public interface ChampionInterface {
    public void tabInteraction(int id);
    public void soldierPasser(int soldierInt, int divisionInt, String first, String last);
    public void drawerListViewSelection(int selection);
    public void adderFragDivReference(int divIndex);
    public void setListViewSelection(int selection);
}
`
```

Comment: your data model is sqlite db, so why are you using BaseAdapter? use SimpleCursorAdapter instead, see Notepatd demo: http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html and you will see how your life become easier...

Comment: Thanks!  The cursor adapter definitely makes everything a whole lot cleaner.  The problem still persists.  It is because my database only updates on my `onCreate()` method of my fragment, when it needs to update the table on an `onClick()` action.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/notepad-ex2.html ^F Step 3

Answer (score 0):

Try to call

```
Soldier toDelete = adapter.getItem(selection);
databaseHelper.deleteSoldier(toDelete); 

if(//deletion successful){
   adpater.removeItem(selection);
}
```

This way you are not reloading objects from the db you are actually not using!